# Copy of overleaf compiles differently

Tags: citing, overleaf

I copied a overleaf project in 2 ways: using the copy function as well as by downloading/uploading the project. The copy compiles differenty: especially the citations looks different, since the year does not appear any more while referencing a book.

Does anyone have a tip how to fix it?

Comment: A suggestion (I had a similar issue some weeks ago): check if compiler and TeXLive version are set to the same for both projects. You can do it in overleaf's left menu.

Comment: it sounds more a question for overleaf support than here but check in the left side ar which version of texlive is in use. if you copy a project it will be using the version of that project which may be texlive 2020 or 2021 but if you re-upload as a new project it will default to 2022

Comment: Changing texlive helped :-) I did not know about that option. Thank you very much to you all :-)